# bootstrap popover works second time in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am not getting the pop over when I click on the link

Click Me !!!

It calls ajax method & fetches data which is a template something like this.

```
   <html>
    <div>
    <p><b> Example</b> </p>
    </div>
    </html>
```

Now I want to show this template as popover which shows up on second click onwords

My code is this

```
<script>
$("a[rel=popover]")
    .click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/servercall',
            success: function(data) {
        $("#myId").popover({placement: 'top', html:true, trigger: 'click',content: data});
                }
          });

     });


 </script>
```

I search over it & found that setting 'data-content' attribute solves this issue. like this
    $("#myId").attr('data-content',data).popover('show');

but shoes data as plain text & not the way it should like in html aligned format.

Comment: what is `#myId` referring to? do you have an example we can look at?

Comment: it's a hyperlink.         <li><a href="#" id="myId"    rel="popover"  >Click Me</a></li>